# How can we get the multiple elements with one expression like using for loop

Tags: xpath, cypress, cypress-each

We have 5 elements and we need to match the text of all 5 elements with some expected text.

Say `//div[@class="xyz"]` is the common element selector and for 1st element we need to use `(//div[@class="xyz"])[1]`, and so-on using a for-loop.

```js
for (i=0; i<xyz.length; i++) {
  cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"])[i]')
}
```

How can I do this in Cypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Cypress test a for-loop is implemented with `.each()`

```js
const expectedText = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
cy.xpath('(//div[@class="xyz"]')
  .each(($el,index) => {
    expect($el.text()).to.eq(expectedText[index])
  })
```

or

```js
const expectedText = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
cy.get('div.xyz')
  .each(($el,index) => {
    expect($el.text()).to.eq(expectedText[index])
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `.eq()` command?

```js
cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"])').eq(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach` loop to iterate over the texts. And in the XPath, you can use the index values from the forEach loop. Something like:

```js
var textArray = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5']

for (let [index, text] of textArray.entries()) {
  cy.xpath(`//div[@class="xyz"])[${index}]`).should('have.text', text)
}
```

And in case you just have one text that you want to validate for the 5 elements, you can use the traditional for loop with 5 iterations something like:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cy.xpath(`//div[@class="xyz"])[${i}]`).should('have.text', 'some text')
}
```